# How to use FluentValidation to display UI error for either or fields

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have an MVC 3 app which uses FluentValidation to express validation logic on some ViewModel objects.

One of the objects has two properties as follows:

```
  [DisplayNameAttribute(UiConstants.Telephone)]
  public string Telephone { get; set; }

  [DisplayNameAttribute(UiConstants.Email)]
  public string Email { get; set; }
```

The rule is that EITHER of these properties must be entered at the UI and I want the UI to display a validation message for at least one of the fields (Email) when the user hits Submit but without doing a PostBack.

I can get the validation to work with the following code in the validator

```
               RuleFor(contact => contact.Email)
                .Must((contact, email) => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email) != string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contact.Telephone))
                .WithMessage(ValidationConstants.EmailOrTelephone);
```

and this will display my validation error message at the UI, but only after a PostBack.

I have also used a Custom Validator as follows

```
            Custom(contactUs =>
            {
                return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contactUs.Telephone) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contactUs.Email)
                    ? new ValidationFailure("Email", ValidationConstants.EmailOrTelephone)
                    : null;
            });
```

but this behaves in the same way.

Will this not work the way I am hoping?

**Is there another way to do the validator to get the error message to display in the UI without doing a PostBack?**

I know that I could also use DataAnnotations but I specifically want to do this with FluentValidation.

Many thanks

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for **client-side validation** - this isn't specific to FluentValidation or DataAnnotations.  Both mechanisms will work server-side automatically (you have to wire FluentValidation up to do this automatically after model binding, or run it manually).

If you want client-side validation with ASP.NET MVC, you'll also have to wire that bit up.  [This](http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2011/01/28/aspnet-mvc-3-client-side-validation-summary-with-jquery-validation-unobtrusive-javascript.aspx) blog entry may help.

One note though - your Custom validator won't work by default (you'd have to replicate that validation in jQuery on the client).  Check out [this](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc) article on FluentValidation; here's an excerpt that shows what validators should "just work" client-side without rewriting your own:

> Note that FluentValidation will also work with ASP.NET MVC's
> client-side validation, but not all rules are supported. For example,
> any rules defined using a condition (with When/Unless), custom
> validators, or calls to Must will not run on the client side. The
> following validators are supported on the client:
>
> *NotNull/NotEmpty
>
> *Matches (regex)
>
> *InclusiveBetween (range)
>
> *CreditCard
>
> *Email
>
> *EqualTo (cross-property equality comparison)
>
> *Length